# set every 1st and fourth element with a class

Tags: php

I have a jquery carousel set to 620px wide. I am using the grid 960 to place the images inside. I show 4 images at a time.

In order to do that I set the every first image class to 'grid_2 alpha' and every fourth to 'grid_2 omega' in the group of 4 shown while all in between I set to just grid_2.

This gives me the 620px I need. I am pulling from the database and I am trying to set the class dynamically but cant quite get every first and fourth in the group with the classes.

```
                    <?php $loopIndex = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($pub_values as $v) { 
                    if($v['pub_of_the_month'] == 1)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($loopIndex == 1 || $grid_class=="grid_2 omega") $grid_class="grid_2 alpha";
                            else if($loopIndex%4 == 0) $grid_class="grid_2 omega"; 
                            else $grid_class="grid_2"; 
                          $filename = "images/pub_images/120x160/".$v['id'].".jpg";
                          if (!file_exists($filename)) $filename = "images/pub_images/120x160/blank.gif";       
                    ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $grid_class?>">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?=$filename;?>" alt="<?=$v['name'];?>" width="120" height="160" />
                                <?=$v['name'];?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php $loopIndex = $loopIndex + 1; } }?>
```

The above code is my best attempt of achieving the following.

Images

1 - grid_2 alpha

2 - grid_2

3 - grid_2

4 - grid_2 omega

5 - grid_2 alpha

6 - grid_2

7 - grid_2

8 - grid_2 omega

9 - grid_2 alpha

Comment: sorry, I will try my best. I wish to set the first image to grid_2 alpha and every four after that. I also wish to set the fourth image to grid_2 omega and plus for after that. Images 2,3,6,7 etc set to just grid_2

Comment: Are [CSS3's `:nth-child()`s](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) out of the question?

Comment: yes sadly, wont be supported by most users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple math, dividing with a remainder.

Maybe you can figure out by looking a this code:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++){
    echo "\n $i ";
    if($i % 4 == 1){
        echo " alpha";
    }elseif($i % 4 == 0){
        echo " omega";
    }
}
```

Live example: http://codepad.org/LIepxlJm

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should just use a for-loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i< sizeof($pub_values); $i++) { 
   $classes =['grid_2'];
   if($i%4 == 0) $classes[] = 'alpha';
   if($i%4 == 3) $classes[] = 'omega';
}
```

edit: this is just trying to show an approach, not trying to be syntactically correct.
in the end, you want to join (or implode in php) your classes to get the string.... (not implemented for you either)

Comment: Calling `sizeof()` in a loop? *tisk* *tisk*

Comment: thanks for mentioning it, maybe he could do `foreach($pub_values as $i => $val )` and use that $i (depends on his array)